# Winding number of image curve

Tags: complex-analysis

How many turns does $f(z) = z^{40} + 4$ make about the origin in the complex plane after one circuit of $|z| = 2$?

Comment: Please refrain from using **ALL CAPS** in a post when possible, and always refrain from doing so in a title.

Comment: Can you solve it for $g(z) = z^{40}$?

Comment: "HELP! HELP! I'M BEING REPRESSED!"

Comment: No I don't know the method. Do you know of one?

Comment: I edited your title to remove the CAPS and make it more descriptive.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't used this site before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that your curve is homotopic to the image of $|z|=2$ under $g(z)=z^{40}$ in $\mathbb C\backslash 0$. (Draw a picture if you aren't convinced.) Because the curves are homotopic, their winding numbers are the same, so you can just compute the winding number of the image of $|z|=2$ under $g(z)$ to get the answer. This is easy.

Comment: Sorry I really don't understand. How do you compute that?

Comment: @Jonathon Do the integral in the definition of the winding number.